# Solspace Freeform Recipient Value in Notification

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a similar question to what was ask here: [Getting Recipient Names/email address in Notification](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13250/getting-recipient-names-email-address-in-notification)

But I would like to capture the names using a drop down menu instead of multiple values.

Comment: Thomas, please post the code you've tried that isn't working.