# How can I get the Freeform (free v.) Recipient Name value into a notification template?

Tags: solspace-freeform, jquery, notification

My question is very similar to this one:

[Getting Recipient Names/email address in Notification](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13250/getting-recipient-names-email-address-in-notification?rq=1)

However I need to use a select field rather than checkboxes.

I've tried this but it doesn't work (I used `.change` instead of `.click` and `:selected` instead of `:checked`):

```
$(function($){
    var $chosenRecipients   = $('[name="freeform_product"]');
    var $recipientChecks    = $('[name^="the_product"]');

    $recipientChecks.change(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $chosenRecipients.val('');
            var newVal = [];
            $('input[name^="the_product"] option').each(function(){
                if ($(this).is(':selected'))
                {
                    newVal.push($(this).val());
                }
            });
            $chosenRecipients.val(newVal.join(', '));
        },0);
    });
});
```

The relevant HTML/EE code:

```
{exp:freeform:form
    collection="Contact Us"
    form:id="contact_us"

    recipients="yes"   
    recipient_template="contact_us_page"

    recipient1="name|email1@address.com"  
    recipient2="name|email1@address.com"  
    recipient3="name|email1@address.com"  
    recipient4="name|email1@address.com" 
    recipient5="name|email1@address.com"
}

<input type="text" value="" id="freeform_product" name="freeform_product">
<label for="the_product" class="span6">Product<br>
<select name="the_product" id="the_product">
    <option value="">------Select------</option>
    {freeform:recipients}
    <option value="{freeform:recipient_name}">{freeform:recipient_name}</option>
    {/freeform:recipients}
</select>
</label>
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I've added a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yL432nvc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your fiddle, use this as your JS :

```
    var newVal = [];
    $('select[name="the_product"]').change(function(e){
        $('input#freeform_product').val('');
        $('select[name="the_product"] option').each(function(){
            if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
                newVal.push($(this).attr('value'));
            }
        });
        $('input#freeform_product').val(newVal.join(', '));
    });
```

Very much simplified, you had a scope issue around newVal...

PS> JUST this, no other JS...

Comment: Sweet, this totally works for populating the text field from the options... Thank you so much!  Unfortunately the other piece of my issue still exists - it's not pulling that value into the notification template...

Comment: No problemo, please mark as the answer though, it helps the site and it's other users (and bumps my rep a bit more, I must have meaningless points!! LOL)

Comment: points, POINTS!!! Woot Woot!! hehe, Glad I could help you out mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your JS at issue here or getting the value in the notification template itself?

If it's the JS, you have the `each()` iteration wrong. you're targetting the `<select>` element on the each, but what you want is the child `<options>`.

Try this, replace :

```
[...]
        $recipientChecks.each(function(){
            if ($(this).is(':selected'))
            {
                newVal.push( $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').text());
            }
        });
[...]
```

With :

```
[...]
        $('input[name^="the_product"] option').each(function(){
            if ($(this).is(':selected'))
            {
                newVal.push($(this).val());
            }
        });
[...]
```

Edit : I also notice you're getting the id's not the values of the option's, ammended example..

You can also make your hidden input a text input for debugging so you can see if its working without inspection...

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  I tried what you've suggested (I will update my question with the changes), but the text field - `freeform_product` isn't populating with the value of the selected `the_product` option...  So I guess my issue at this time is in the JS.

Comment: bah, darned `<option>` tags, you could try `$(this).html()` instead of `$(this).val()` to get the innards of each option. You could also drop the `setTimeout` as thats not helping anything!!